# Custom interceptor in Spring Boot [ADD HTTP REQUEST HEADER]

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, interceptor, spring-restcontroller

I trying to create a custom interceptor in a spring boot app for add a header in each http request.

**for example:**
`POSTMAN  --[GET: http://some_url] --> INTERCEPTOR -- [ADD HEADER "ID"] --> RestController [GET HEADER ID].`

I tried to create an interceptor like this

```
@Component
public class LogRequestHandler implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogRequestHandler.class);

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, 
                ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
    String trackingId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8);
    long timestamp = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    log.info("Request [{}] {} {}", trackingId, httpRequest.getMethod(), httpRequest.getURI());
    httpRequest.getHeaders().add("TRACKING_ID", trackingId);
    httpRequest.getHeaders().add("TIMESTAMP", String.valueOf(timestamp));
    return clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
  }
}
```

but i don't know how add this to spring configuration :(( 
Can someone confirm if my approach it's correct or suggest other idea?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in spring `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` you have the method dedicated for that

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
```

so you can do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired 
  HandlerInterceptor yourInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(yourInterceptor);
  }
}
```

Comment: so, my interceptor should look like this ? https://ibb.co/31GYZLz 
Exist a way to add a header to request ???
Thx.